# Publishing an AVRO messages to topic via Kafka REST

Tags: confluence-rest-api, kafka-topic

Getting below error when producing message to topic.

```
"message": "Cannot construct instance of `io.confluent.kafkarest.entities.v3.ProduceRequest$ProduceRequestData`, problem: 'schema_version=17' cannot be used with 'serializer'."
```

I'm trying to send an avro message to the topic (Confluent Cloud) but getting a serializer error.

Reference: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#records-v3

```
curl --location 'https://{host}/kafka/v3/clusters/{cluster}/topics/{topic-name}/records' \
--header 'Confluent-Identity-Pool-Id: {pool-id}' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer jwt_token' \
--data '{
    "partition_id": 0,
    "key": {
        "type": "BINARY",
        "data": "Zm9vYmFy"
    },
    "value": {
        "type": "AVRO",
        "subject":"greetings.request-value",
        "schema_version":17,
        "data": {
            "greetings": "hello"
        }
}'
```

Comment: It didn't work. Got this error. {
    "error_code": 415,
    "message": "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"
}

Comment: Actually, I'm using produce record v3 endpoint and it's only supporting application/json.